# How to combine arrays depending on user selection?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode

I want to see what user selected like the name of book and its assocaited chapters

I did this

```
struct bookChpt {
    var book:[String] = []
    var chapter:[[Int]] = []
}

let chptSelected = [bookChpt(book:bookArr,chapter:chptArr)]

var bookArr:[String] = []
var chptArr:[[Int]] = []
```

I have this in `viewDidLoad()`

```
if let bTitle = result.value(forKey: "bookTitle") as? String
{
    bookArr.append(bTitle)

}
if let cNo = result.value(forKey: "chpNo") as? [Int]
{
    chptArr.append(cNO)
}
print(chptSelected)
```

I am getting this

> bookChpt( book: ["Hobbit", "LOTR"], chapter: [[3,5],4])

but I like to see this

> ["Hobbit", 3, 5], ["LOTR", 4]

Comment: FWIW developers usually avoid bookArray or ArrayOfBooks, they usually just do books ie just use plural, it makes it more as if you are reading English

Comment: @Honey, appreciate your advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of possibilities.  You could add a function to the struct to display its contents in the way you want:

```
struct BookChapter {
    var book:[String] = []
    var chapter:[[Int]] = []

    func display() -> [[Any]] {
        var output = [[Any]]()
        for i in 0..<book.count {
            output.append([book[i], chapter[i]])
        }
        return output
    }
}
```

Or you could modify the structure of the struct to contain the book and chapters as tuples:

```
struct BookChapter {
    var book:[(String, [Int])]
}
```

Going a bit further, anywhere you see a loop - such as in the display function above - you might also consider using `map` to achieve the same thing:

```
func display() -> Any {
    return book.enumerated().map { $0.element + " " + chapter[$0.offset].description }
}
```

Comment: If I modify it so as to contain them as tuples, then what is chptSelected going to be?

Comment: It would be bookChpt(book: [("Hobbit", [3, 5]), ("LOTR", [4])]) which, admittedly isn't precisely the answer that you asked for.  If you want closer control over the output then you may be better with the first part of the answer and add an inner loop that handles each chapter individually rather than as a group in my example.

Answer (score 1):

If you use an Dictionary like this, you can print the key and value whatever way you wanted.

```
var bookChapters = [String: [Int]]()

bookChapters["Hobbit"] = [1,2,3]
bookChapters["Hobbit"]?.append(contentsOf: [4])


for (book, chapter) in bookChapters {
    print("\(book): \(chapter)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `struct` to

```
struct BookChapt {
    var book: String = ""
    var chapter: [Int] = []
}
```

and in `viewDidLoad()`

```
var bookName = ""
var chapters:[Int] = []
if let bTitle = result.value(forKey: "bookTitle") as? String
{
    bookName = bTitle
}
if let cNo = result.value(forKey: "chpNo") as? [Int]
{
    chapters = cNo
}
let chptSelected = BookChapt(book: bookName, chapter: chapters)
print(chptSelected)
```